# Proof of (w * w^R)^R = w*w^R

Tags: algorithm, theory, proof

**Question: if w exist in T*, prove that (w * w^R)^R = w * w^R**

Hi, I am new to theories of algorithms, and I am having trouble understanding how to prove this, if someone can hint me towards the right direction that would be much appreciated.

**Note:** R means the string is reversed, ex: (abc)^R = cba

**Also Note:** * means concatenation so (abc * def) = abcdef

Comment: Is it a homework?

Comment: It follows from 2 lemmas: 1) `(s^R)^R = s` (for any `s` in `T*`). And 2) `(u*v)^R = v^R * u^R` for any `u,v` in `T*`. Can you prove these two lemmas and then show how the result follows?

Comment: @JohnColeman Thanks, this really helped me do the proof

Comment: Not a programming question - try http://cstheory.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 0):

In *general case*, try using *group theory* (you even have a *hint*: "Also Note: * means concatenation so `(abc * def) = abcdef`"):

```
  a, b, c, ...          - (characters)    - group's elements (generators in fact)
  a * b       == ab     - (concatenation) - group's operation
  ε                     - (empty string)  - group's 1 
  a..z**-1    == z..a   - rule for the item reversing; a**-1 == a
```

So far, so good, string reversing is `**-1` operation, for any `ab...yz` item we have:

```
  (ab...yz)((ab..yz)^R) == ab..yz * zy ..ba == ab..yzzy..ba

    since zz == z * z == ε (z == z**-1) 

  we have

    ab..yzzy..ba == 
    ab..yy..ba == 
    ab..ba ==
    ε
```

Your theorem is quite easy then: change string reversing to `**-1` and have

```
  (w * w**-1)**-1=(w**-1)**-1 * w**-1 == w * w**-1
```

For this *particular case* the group we've built may be an overkill, however, it can be very useful when'll be solving the similar problems.

Comment: Quibble: this is a semigroup rather than a group.